# I tried to Install from sources in openbravo 3.0 but got this error

Tags: postgresql, tomcat6, openbravo

I tried to Install from sources of Openbravo 3.0.
I cloned the project successfully.
next step i tried to run ant install.source
and this is the result I have got

```
D:\openbravopi>ant install.source
Buildfile: D:\openbravopi\build.xml

set.code.rev:

code.rev:

init:

cleanSubfolders:

clean:
   [delete] Deleting directory D:\openbravopi\src-core\build\classes
   [delete] Deleting directory D:\openbravopi\src-core\docs
   [delete] Deleting: D:\openbravopi\src-core\lib\openbravo-core.jar

clean:

clean:

core.lib:

init:
    [mkdir] Created dir: D:\openbravopi\src-core\build\classes
    [mkdir] Created dir: D:\openbravopi\src-core\docs

compile:
    [javac] Compiling 127 source files to D:\openbravopi\src-core\build\classes

build.jar:
      [jar] Building jar: D:\openbravopi\src-core\lib\openbravo-core.jar

build:

copy.core.lib:
     [copy] Copying 1 file to D:\openbravopi\lib\runtime

database.lib:

init:

compile:

build.jar:

jar:

create.database:

create.database:

BUILD FAILED
D:\openbravopi\build.xml:740: The following error occurred while executing this line:
D:\openbravopi\src-db\database\build-create.xml:50: The following error occurred while executing this line:
Target "clean.database.${bbdd.rdbms}" does not exist in the project "openbravo".

Total time: 6 seconds
```

does anyone know the solution to this problem?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Actually I skipped the step `ant setup`.  that caused the error!  if the steps were followed according to the instructions, the set up should be carried out fine.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because ant does not know what ${bbdd.rdbms} is.
solution is

1. go to {your openbravo folder}/config and look for file Opernbavo.properties.template
2. copy Opernbavo.properties.template and rename it to Opernbavo.properties
3. inside Opernbavo.properties you might need to change some username or password to access PostgreSQL in my case I have to set bbdd.systemPassword=root

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

you have to run "ant setup" first ;)